# when changing from MMap to Wiretiger in Mongodb would there be any client side changes required

Tags: mongodb

I am using php driver ver 1.6.14 and we are planning to upgrade from our mongo Storage Engine from MMAP to WireTiger. Doing this would there be any requirement to change on the client side.

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. Storage backend is the server's implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-standalone-wiredtiger/) before moving on to wiredTiger.
The limitation I'd see would be between the version of your driver and the version of Mongod you are running.
Apart from that, it's pretty much internal to MongoDB itself.